# Cronjobs and AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services

My application require this 3 cronjobs to work properly:

```
00 00 * * * wget http://www.mysite.com/cron/archivebenefits > /dev/null 2>&1
*/15 * * * * wget http://www.mysite.com/cron/archiveevents > /dev/null 2>&1
*/15 * * * * wget http://www.mysite.com/cron/sendlists > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk and the problem is that I can not setup them.
As the cronjobs run remotely requests, I can use them outside of my servers too. Anyone have any ideas?

NOTE: Use an EC2 instance for them is unfeasible due to the price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure them through `.ebextensions`, ask explained here: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/10/customize-elastic-beanstalk-using-configuration-files.html

See similar question: [AWS Elastic Beanstalk, running a cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077095/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-cronjob)