# scheduled http call on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been searching for a while and think I have part of the information I need but just need some assistance putting it all together.

What I'm trying to achieve is to call a URL (a codeigniter controller) on a regular basis e.g. every 5 minutes which will go through my database mail queue and send the mail using amazon SES.

So far I have successfully created the controller, model, DB and SES is working just fine. The controller sends 10 emails at a time and it all works fine when I manually hit the URL.

I'm not too familiar with cron jobs, but think this is where I need to head.

My application is set up on Elastic beanstalk on AWS.

I think that I need a folder called `.ebextensions` in my web root, with a file called `something.config` in it, where I can put some 'container commands'. I also think I will need to include 'leader_only: true' in there somewhere to avoid my replicated instances doing the same jobs.

When I don't understand is what should my container command be, considering controller is '`http://myapplication/process_mail`' ? From examples I've seen I couldn't see how it determines the frequency, or even the code that 'calls' the URL.

In my controller, I previously had the following code to ensure it could only be called from the command line. Is this something I can keep and have or will the container command just hit the URL like any other user?

```
if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) {
            echo "Access Denied";
            return;
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help at all. I think i just need help with what should go in the config file, but then again I may have gone down completely the wrong path altogether!

### UPDATE:

So far I've got as far as this:

I believe i need to run the application from the commandline like this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

so my command would be `php index.php process_mail`

So what I actually need is help with running this command evey 5 minutes. This is what I have so far:

```
container_commands:
  send_mail: 
    command: php index.php process_mail
    leader_only: true
```

But what I don't understand is how I get this to run every 5 minutes, rather than just when the instance is set up. Do I need to create a cron job file on instance creation, with the php command in it instead?

### Update 2:

To anyone else with the same problem, i got this sorted in the end like this:

an ebextensions file that looks like this: (`.ebextensions/mail_queue.config`)

```
container_commands:
  01_send_mail:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/process_mail.txt > /etc/cron.d/process_mail && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/process_mail"
    leader_only: true
```

a file called process_mail.txt in the same folder that looks like this:

```
# The newline at the end of this file is extremely important.  Cron won't run without it.
*/5 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/app/current/index.php process_mail > /dev/null
```

So, every 5 minutes it runs via the cmd line the codeigniter main index file, passing in the controller name.

thanks to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15233848/2604392

Answer (score -1):

I would set up the cron job to talk to the url, then store result in a MySQL database. Then regular PHP or any other app can connect to MySQL and access the data. That's the suggested way to connect to Twitter since a few months, so you can find info on how to do this floowing search for Twitter connectivity. 
Hope this helps

By the way, while writing an email generating PHP script, I noticed that I have to slow down the pace of email sending to avoid being flagged as spammer. I added a delay of 2 seconds between emails and it did the job. My database was only 2500 so no big deal (except taking care of changing the PHP_MAXEXECUTION time variable)...

Comment: Sorry I don't think this is what I'm looking for. It's nothing to do with Twitter or even the MySQL db as I'm just trying to get elastic beanstalk to run some code on a regular basis. Thanks anyway though.