# Crontab in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rake-task

I am doing a cron tab in AWS - Elastic Beanstalk with Ruby on Rails 3, but I don't know what is wrong.

I have this code in my **.ebextensions/default.config**

```
container_commands:
  01remove_old_cron_jobs:
    command: "crontab -r || exit 0"
  02send_test_email:
    command: crontab */2 * * * * rake send_email:test
    leader_only: true
```

I receive this error:

```
Failed on instance with return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command 02send_test_email failed .
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried next:

**crontab.txt**

```
*/2 * * * * rake send_email:test > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**default.config**

```
02_crontab:
  command: "cat .ebextensions/crontab.txt | crontab"
  leader_only: true
```

RESULT: No errors, but it does not work.

**UPDATE 2**

**crontab.sh**

```
crontab -l > /tmp/cronjob
#CRONJOB RULES
echo "*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://localhost/crontabs/send_test_email > /dev/null 2>&1" >> /tmp/cronjob
#echo "*/2 * * * * rake send_email:test > /dev/null 2>&1" >> /tmp/cronjob

crontab /tmp/cronjob
rm /tmp/cronjob
echo 'Script successful executed, crontab updated.'
```

**default.config**

```
02_crontab:
  command: "/bin/bash .ebextensions/crontab.sh"
  leader_only: true
```

RESULT: Works with url, but not with rake task.

Answer (score 11):

#### Updated for 2018

In order to get this to work on the latest version of Elastic Beanstalk, I added the following to my `.ebextensions`:

**.ebextensions/0005_cron.config**

```
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      56 11 * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && cd /var/app/current && /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle exec /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/rake send_email:test >> /var/app/current/log/cron.log 2>&1

commands:
  remove_old_cron:
    command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

#### How I got there:

There are four main issues to confront when trying to cron a rake task in AWS EB:

1. The first hurdle is making sure all of your EB and Rails environment variables are loaded.  I beat my head against the wall a while on this one, but then I discovered [this AWS forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=116826) (login may be required).  Running `. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars` loads all of your environment variables.
2. Then we need to make sure we `cd` into the current app directory using `cd /var/app/current`.
3. Next we need to know where to find the `bundle` and `rake` executables. They are not installed in the normal `bin` directories, but are located in a directory specific to your ruby version.  To find out where your executables are located, ssh into your EB server (`eb ssh`) and then type the following:

   ```
   $ cd /var/app/current
   $ which bundle
   /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle
   $ which rake
   /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/rake
   ```

   You could probably guess the directory based on your ruby version, but the above commands will let you know for sure.  Based on the above, your can build your rake command as:

   ```
   /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle exec /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/rake send_email:test
   ```

   NOTE: If you update your ruby version, you will likely need to update your cron config as well. This is a little brittle. I'd recommend making a note in your README on this.  Trust me, six months from now, you will forget.
4. The fourth thing to consider is logging.  I'd recommend logging to the same location as your other rails logs.  We do this by tacking on `>> /var/app/current/log/cron.log 2>&1` to the end of our command string.

Putting all of this together leads to a `cron` command string of:

```
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && cd /var/app/current && /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle exec /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/rake send_email:test >> /var/app/current/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Finally, I referenced the latest [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/) to build an `.ebextensions` config file for my `cron` command.  The result was the `.ebextensions/0005_cron.config` file displayed at the top of this answer.

Comment: Since you're loading in the environment variables, I think you should be able to use `$RUBY_ROOT` in place of the actual path (e.g. `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4`) to avoid the eventual pain of "why hasn't this task been running?" when the Ruby version inevitably updates.

Comment: @Matt, Excellent idea. I have not had time to test it yet, but if you are confident, feel free to edit this answer.

Comment: `/opt/rubies/ruby-current` is linked to the current ruby version on recent Beanstalk ruby machines, so you can use that instead of a path for a specific ruby version.

Comment: A more verbose command string but without hardwired paths: `. $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)/envvars && cd $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir) && . $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)/use-app-ruby.sh && bundle exec rake -T`

Comment: If it helps anyone, my Node.js Amazon Linux 2 environment didn't have the `envvars` file. `get-config` is an alternative, but it is not yet on Amazon Linux 2 (as of June 2020). A workaround that helped me is available here: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/issues/111#issuecomment-640949286

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same issue. Though I figured out that the reason that rake task doesn't run correctly on eb is because of RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV and BUNDLE_WITHOUT

Defaults of eb:

```
RACK_ENV: production
RAILS_ENV: production
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: test:development
```

When the cron runs rake task, it runs in development mode, and gives gem not found error, as gems grouped in development are not installed.

you can see this by changing your cron a bit
from:

```
*/2 * * * * rake send_email:test > /dev/null 2>&1
```

to:

```
*/2 * * * * cd /var/app/current/ && /usr/bin/bundle exec /usr/bin/rake send_email:test > /tmp/cron_log 2>&1
```

and then checking the /tmp/cron_log file
To know the location of bundle and rake, run

```
which bundle
which rake
```

I tried setting RAILS_ENV in command in cron, but that didn't work aswell
One quick fix is to set

```
BUNDLE_WITHOUT to null
```

**EDIT:**

Finally I got it to work,

.ebextensions/.config

```
files:
  "/tmp/cron_jobs" :
    mode: "000777"
    content: |
      1 10 * * * cd /var/app/current/ && RACK_ENV=production rake some:task >> /var/app/current/log/cron_log 2>&1
    encoding: plain
container_commands:
  01_delete_cron_jobs:
    command: "crontab -r -u webapp || exit 0"
  02_add_cron_jobs:
    command: "crontab /tmp/cron_jobs -u webapp"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  - option_name: RAILS_ENV
    value: production
  - option_name: RACK_ENV
    value: production
```

Notice the '-u webapp' when removing and adding cron, this will run this cron under user webapp. The above will also run in production mode. And the output will be dumped in log/cron_log file.

If the above wont work then adding 'Bundle exec' before 'rake some:task' might work.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen these used with separate files in .ebextensions, such as:

```
  02send_test_email:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/crontab | crontab"
    leader_only: true
```

I haven't gotten around to it yet, but I took note of this along the way.  Let us know if this works.

[This stackoverflow post has much more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077095/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-cronjob)

After Update 1/2:

Cron doesn't know where `rake` is.  Your application runs from `/var/app/current`, and you need to be running `bundle exec rake` from that directory.

Elastic beanstalk is horrible with logging errors, to get this right, `ssh` to the machine and experiment until you have the commands right, then put this back into your cron script.  You can even try and re-run some of the eb scripts as found in the logs, then reverse that into your `ebextensions` files.

Comment: No works for me. i have a crontab.txt with `*/2 * * * * rake send_email:test > /dev/null 2>&1` and nothing. No errors, but no work.

Comment: See Update 1 and Update 2.

Comment: any example to running the `bundle exec` from `/var/app/current`?