# How do I install a Python script on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've built a Python script that runs continuously, generating push notifications through Amazon AWS's SNS service. As long as the script is running in my Terminal, then my app receives push notifications just fine.

I'd like to move this script up to Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk, but I'm stuck: how do I bundle up the script in such a way that it'll run on Amazon?

I've tried several tutorials, but most of them are geared towards building API's or web apps - I'm just interested in running a script.

Also - the script uses try/except statements, so it only very rarely ever crashes - but is there a way to restart the script automagically?

Answer (score 0):

This Already-answered SO question might answer your question:

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk, running a cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077095/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-cronjob)