# How do I run a python script once at startup on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run a python script 'indefinitely' on an EB instance, automatically once deployed (I don't want to SSH in). To do that, I think I should run

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && nohup python myscriptname.py &
```

*after* the Elastic Beanstalk instance is deployed. But where do I put the above command to automatically run this post deployment?

I have looked at [How do I install a Python script on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154959/how-do-i-install-a-python-script-on-amazons-elastic-beanstalk?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I don't think a cron job is suitable for me.

I have used `container_commands` before but they seem to run pre-deployment.

> Container commands run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed.

**How do I run a post-deploy script?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always there's a few ways to do this in AWS.  You could start an instance, customize away, then create an AMI from this image.  You could then tell beanstalk to use this [custom AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html)

Or could use [ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to custom your instance on creation and app restart.  I'm currently using this to install (if not already instaled) logstash and download the latest GeoLiteCity db when my app starts up.

Here's a sample from the docs

```
container_commands:
  collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
  01syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  99customize:
    command: "scripts/customize.sh"
```

Comment: I didn't get how will this start a let's say, cron job, post-starting the app?

Comment: you could add a script that would create the cron job.  add that to your .ebextensions dir and call it from one of your extensions files.  check the docs, there's a few examples.