# What is the exact behavior of the is_leader flag on Amazon Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, distributed, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is the exact behavior of the 'is_leader' flag on an Amazon Beanstalk deployment? I could not find any exhaustive documentation on it. More specifically:

1. What is the value on a single instance environment?
2. Does Amazon properly reset the is_leader value when nodes are added/removed from an environment, either manually or via auto-scaling?
3. If that flag is automatically reset by Amazon for a node, does Amazon take care of restarting the instance to make sure that flag is taken into account by the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_leader` is a tag, applied by AWS deployment process to the first created instance. As you mentioned, the documentation on `is_leader` is very scarce, here's what I was able to find:

> The idea of a leader only exists during the execution of a deployment
>   in an environment update. After deployment has executed, there isn't a
>   concept of a leader anymore, though you could determine which instance
>   had been the leader if needed for debugging purposes.

The answers to your questions:

> What is the value on a single instance environment?

`is_leader` is not applicable to single instance environment, so the tag is not set.

> Does Amazon properly reset the is_leader value when nodes are
>   added/removed from an environment, either manually or via
>   auto-scaling?

Leader node is not immune from being removed from an environment. If it's removed, there's no "leader" re-assignment. There are ways to prevent it from being shut down by AutoScaling: [Configure Instance Termination Policy for Your Auto Scaling Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/us-termination-policy.html)

> If that flag is automatically reset by Amazon for a node, does Amazon
>   take care of restarting the instance to make sure that flag is taken
>   into account by the application?

The flag is not reset. Once the leader node is gone from the environment, the tag will only reappear on the rebuild.

Sources:

- [Leaderless Beanstalk instances (or detecting the leader)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=473569)
- [AWS Elastic Beanstalk, running a cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077095/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-cronjob/14110976)