# Using MySQL LOCK TABLE to ensure one instance of cron job in cloud (auto-scaling EC2 / ELB)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After searching hi and lo for the best way to run a cron job when deploying an app using on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with auto-scaling enabled, I came across a few solutions.

Problem: the problem with running `cron` on beanstalk (or auto-scaling cloud) is that every instance will have it's own cron daemon and the script will run many copies simultaneously (on each EC2 instance) when it auto-scales.

**Solutions offered:**

1. Use a worker instance + SQS

   - Problem: it's too complicated and I don't want to be billed for an additional instance for one simple cron job like sending an alert to the user.
2. Use cronlock

   - Problem: requires you to install a central redis sever.

**My own solution:**

My site already has a Mysql server (Amazon RDS) and so I was thinking that maybe this can work?

1. I can create a table with just one field `last_run`.
2. Create the following script and add it to cron daemon instead:

   1. `LOCK TABLES crond WRITE`
   2. Read the value in `crond`.`last_run`
   3. If `time()` - `last_run` > 5 (i.e. 5 seconds have elapsed) then I update the time in the `last_run` field to current `time`.
   4. If `time()` - `last_run` < 5 then I exit immediately saying, cron was executed less than 5 seconds ago (i.e. some other instance got the LOCK first)
   5. `UNLOCK TABLES`.
   6. Spawn the actual cron job script(s) if `last_run` > 5 (i.e. #3 is true)

**Questions:**

- Will this be sufficient to ensure that only one copy of cron runs at a time?
- Are there any easier alternatives to what I'm trying to achieve?

Your insights will be helpful before I design and test this thing.

Comment: Have you thought about using a scheduled Lambda function instead of cron? That would certainly be easier than your proposed solution, and much cheaper than a dedicated cron instance.

Comment: hi, no i didn't know about it. Thanks for the tip, i will look for more info about it

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Benastalk contains a mechanism just for that. It's called leader_only and ensures that your cron will run on a single instance rather than all of them. [See documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html).

Here's a stackoverflow thread that tackles just that: [AWS Elastic Beanstalk, running a cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077095/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-cronjob)

If that doesn't work for you, give [Cronally](http://blog.turret.io/run-cron-jobs-on-aws-with-cronally/) a chance.

Comment: Hi, yes I read about it but the problem is the `leader` can be killed after auto-scaling scales down. So it is possible that the cron job will stop working if it is set to leader only :/ (it's mentioned in the update to first answer)

Comment: You are correct. In that case, I guess Cronally is the only "simple" option: http://blog.turret.io/run-cron-jobs-on-aws-with-cronally/