# Schedule a monthly event in PHP

Tags: php, events, php-5.6, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want PHP layer to execute a method (or call a web service) every month. My PHP sits in AWS elastic beanstalk environment.

- My requirement is to run a task every month on a certain time.
- The
  triggering of event execute a PHP code that purges data that sits in
  the RDS as per the defined business rules.

Cron job or MySQL triggers would not help me. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Why would a cron job not help you? Sounds like the perfect tool for the job.

Comment: Agree with @jeroen cron job is the right tool for scheduling

Comment: Cron job is host machine specific right? AWS elastic beanstalk currently helps me to be agnostic to the host machine.

Comment: This may help. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: As well as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077095/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-cronjob

Comment: Thanks but this would not solve my need as it brings in a dependency to a layer outside PHP. Does that mean that there is no solution at all, if schedules needs to be running in a PHP based applications?